# Div text in wrong position on mobile

Tags: html, css, liquid

On my site I have a wishlist button and next to it a div with some text about delivery. On desktop both elements display under the buy now button but on certain mobile devices the div displays above the buy now button. I want it always to be below it.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks

[Desktop - How I want it to look in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcsLe.png)

[Mobile - delivery text showing above buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qvxY.png)

```
{% if settings.hide_wishlist == false %}
{% if template != 'search' %}
<button class="btn-wishlist button btn-default wishlist-btn" data-product-handle="{{ product.handle }}" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'products.product.add_to_wishlist' | t }}" data-original-title="{{ 'products.product.add_to_wishlist' | t }}"  >
  <span>{{ 'products.product.add_to_wishlist' | t }}</span>
</button>
{% else %}
<button class="btn-wishlist button btn-default wishlist-btn" data-product-handle="{{ item.handle }}" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'products.product.add_to_wishlist' | t }}" data-original-title="{{ 'products.product.add_to_wishlist' | t }}"  >
  <span>{{ 'products.product.add_to_wishlist' | t }}</span>
</button>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
<div class="delivery-bar">
  <svg width="23" height="16" viewBox="0 0 23 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M17.4256 8.00195V6.9082H22.6793L19.6066 2.80664H14.2734V13.2793H15.8649C16.0392 14.3758 16.9362 15.2152 18.0125 15.2152C19.0889 15.2152 19.9859 14.3785 20.1601 13.2793H22.9869V8.00195H17.4256ZM18.0125 14.1215C17.377 14.1215 16.8593 13.5691 16.8593 12.891V12.8883V12.8773C16.867 12.2074 17.3846 11.6605 18.0125 11.6605C18.6404 11.6605 19.1581 12.2074 19.1658 12.8773V12.891C19.1658 13.5691 18.6481 14.1215 18.0125 14.1215Z" fill="#AFAFAF"/>
<path d="M12.3215 0.783203H1.67062C1.11706 0.783203 0.666016 1.26445 0.666016 1.85508V12.2102C0.666016 12.8008 1.11706 13.282 1.67062 13.282H3.97968C4.15395 14.3785 5.05092 15.218 6.12728 15.218C7.20364 15.218 8.10061 14.3813 8.27488 13.282H13.2492V1.77305C13.2492 1.22891 12.834 0.783203 12.3215 0.783203ZM6.12728 14.1215C5.49171 14.1215 4.97403 13.5691 4.97403 12.891V12.8883V12.8773C4.98172 12.2074 5.4994 11.6605 6.12728 11.6605C6.75516 11.6605 7.27284 12.2074 7.28053 12.8773V12.891C7.28053 13.5691 6.76285 14.1215 6.12728 14.1215Z" fill="#AFAFAF"/>
</svg>
  <span>Delivery in 2 to 5 working days</span></div>
```

Comment: maybe post the code including the parent div of what you want to be fix and also the css so that we can check and easily debug it.

Comment: or maybe try to add another parent div to the icon with text ( heart and tract icon).